# Express.js: How can I get the ip Address and render a view?

Tags: view, express, request, pug, ip-address

I really think this should be easy. But when I render a jade template, I also want to grab the ip address. My code look like this.

app.js

```
app.get('/', index.home)
```

index.js

```
exports.home = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
};
```

Where can I add something like:

```
var ip = req.header('x-forwarded-for') || req.connection.remoteAddress; //or
console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress);
```

Comment: Do you want to ouput the ip to the console or display it in the view?

Comment: I want to output it to the console for now. Eventually I will want to document it and maybe save it to a database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `req.ip` and make sure you have `app.enable('trust proxy');` if your app is deployed behind a reverse proxy. Express has all the header parsing and proxy logic baked in for you.

Comment: Will req.ip work if I stick that in my index.js? (see original question for file).

Comment: Yes. Anywhere you have access in scope to a req instance.

Comment: @PeterLyons, you're the boss, even 2years later. Thanks you so much!!