# How to get caller ip in node.js + express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In a node.js with express I'd like to define a footer such as (in layout.jade)

```
footer
  p &copy; Me 2015 - Your IP: #{currentIP}
```

in app.js, I have:

```
app.locals.currentIP = function(req) {
  return req.ip;
}
```

When run I get the following error:

```
>    29|     block content    30|     footer
>  > 31|       p &copy; Me 2015 - Your IP: #{currentIP()}    32|    33|     script(
> src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'
> )    34|     script( src='javascripts/bootstrap.js' )
> 
> Cannot read property 'url' of undefined    at app.locals.currentIP
> (c:\workspaces\nodejs.workspace\express_website\app.js:66:13)    at
> eval (eval at <anonymous>
> (c:\workspaces\nodejs.workspace\express_website\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8),
> <anonymous>:199:69)    at eval (eval at <anonymous>
> (c:\workspaces\nodejs.workspace\express_website\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8),
> <anonymous>:225:22)    at res
> (c:\workspaces\nodejs.workspace\express_website\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:219:38)
> at Object.exports.renderFile
> (c:\workspaces\nodejs.workspace\express_website\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:380:38)
> at Object.exports.renderFile
> (c:\workspaces\nodejs.workspace\express_website\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:370:21)
> at View.exports.__express [as engine]
> (c:\workspaces\nodejs.workspace\express_website\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:417:11)
> at View.render
> (c:\workspaces\nodejs.workspace\express_website\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
> at tryRender
> (c:\workspaces\nodejs.workspace\express_website\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
> at EventEmitter.render
> (c:\workspaces\nodejs.workspace\express_website\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express.js: How can I get the ip Address and render a view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192216/express-js-how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-and-render-a-view)

Comment: Maybe, but I've did it like the link recommends, but it does not work. I also have app.enable('trust proxy'); although not mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official doc](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.properties)

> app.locals properties persist throughout the life of the application,
>   in contrast with res.locals properties that are valid only for the
>   lifetime of the request.

In your case it would be better to use `res.locals.currentIP` instead `app.locals.currentIP` because lifetime of `ip` is bound to request rather than application life cycle:

To pass a current user's ip to a view just use:

```
app.post('/get/ip/address', function (req, res) {
    res.locals.currentIP = req.ip
    ...
});
```

In a view you have to use the following snippet to output an accepted ip address.

```
footer
  p &copy; Me 2015 - Your IP: #{locals.currentIP}
```

The error `Cannot read property url of undefined at app.locals.currentIP` due to your `currentIP()` fucntion get executes in another context. My suggestion is don't use function for outputting current user's ip but use scalar value as my code above shows.

You could reside `res.locals.currentIP` in a middleware to get access to `currentIP` variable in all of your views like the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(fucntion (req, res, next) {
   res.locals.currentIP = req.ip;
   next();
});

// routes does after the middleware !
// ...

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Note that your route definitions should be after the middleware that populates `res.locals.currentIP`.

Comment: Ok. I agree with you, but it doesn't work, although it gives no error. Since I want to put it in a footer, so every page should show it, I've put the footer in layout.jade, but where should I put res.locals??? I don't want to put it available on a specific page, like your example, but in the footer.

Comment: You should put `res.locals` either in specific route or in a middleware. I've updated my answer